# Basic XOR function

Tags: python, function

I am in need of some guidance as to how to program an XOR Python function XOR(x,y) that returns the XOR(x,y).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please include the code you've written, even if it is wrong, so that we can see what part of the problem you are stuck on.

Comment: I am just not sure how to create function in general.

Comment: Suggest you read about [function definitions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) in the documentation (or in one of the many books and online Python tutorials).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XOR is defined as a bitwise operation and is a standard operator...That being said there is nothing stopping you from defining it.

```
def XOR(x, y):
    return x ^ y
```